# Flask JSON post request not working

Tags: javascript, python, json, node.js, reactjs

I am using react to submit a form to a flask backend. The data is submitted in json this is an example.

```
add_new_user(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  var user_details = {}
  user_details['fname'] = this.state.first_name
  user_details['last_name'] = this.state.last_name

var post_request = new Request('http://127.0.0.1:5000/add_new_user', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(user_details)
})

fetch(post_request).then(function(response){
    console.log(response)
})
```

On my backend the code looks like this,

```
@app.route('/add_new_user', methods=['POST'])
def add_user():
    content = request.json()
    print content
    return 'user added'
```

However the content variable is null and therefore the printed data on the screen is None. How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try `request.get_json(force=True)`. It's recommended to use `get_json()` instead of the `json()` method. `force=True` allows to ignore content type requirement.

Comment: Thanks, ```force=True``` seems to work but, when I add ```content-type: application/json``` without force=True it still doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: @rksh Make sure you correctly set the content requirement type in the React client. Probably it's some caching issue. Also try to make the request using e.g. curl and see the result. `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"fname":"some first name","last_name":"some last name"}' http://127.0.0.1:5000/add_new_user`

Comment: Hi, sorry yes I correctly setup content type, however I had to install flask-cors extension to enable cors for it to properly work. Thanks

Comment: @rksh You're welcome. Hope the answer was helpful ).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the request content type of Request to `application/json`. Otherwise, it'll be `None`.

Comment: added ```content-type: application/json``` but it doesn't seem to work, why is that?